# App Crashed with error : The String#value field is not present on Android versions >= 6.0

Tags: android

My app is crashing everytime without any proper error in code. Unable to find root cause of error.

Below is the error getting in logcat:

08-13 15:53:40.292 29039-29039/com.example.day.reliefteaching.debug E/art: The String#value field is not present on Android versions >= 6.0

Answer (score 0):

In order to use Apache HTTP client for apps oriented to Android 9 and later try adding this line to Manifest:

`<uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>`